# about draggable elements Jquery UI - Not Fluid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have simple question about jQuery Draggable elements, i use for move divs and change position with some scripts, but i don´t know if it´s problem from jquery UI or what, but always when move, the movement not well

For example when load 2 elements or divs the movement very bad not fluid, i don´t know if howewer understand want to say

**For example i create this simple div for move with function dragabble :**

```
function win_move(idw)
{
jQuery(".wd_"+idw).draggable();
}
```

And the result it´s move the div right, but in one moment go well and in other moment impossible move across screen

Exists other plugin for do this function, or howewer it´s problem from plugin of jquery UI, or need some change o add something more for get the movement will be more fluid

https://jsfiddle.net/gbd8fe3m/6/

Thank´s in advanced

Comment: can we see your full code, or a codepen ?

Comment: yes i can put here in one momoent for see, yes, 2 minutes and i put

Comment: I put the code here : https://jsfiddle.net/gbd8fe3m/6/

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Works in my test site but in jfiddle i cant do works, i only need know if exists other plugin for draggable elements, thank´s

Comment: can you create html without using jquery ?

Comment: You can see here : https://jsfiddle.net/gbd8fe3m/30/

Comment: that's your ui ? but it's not what  was in the image

Comment: Tha´s the HTML code as you tell me the jquery ui for draggable i put in my question, because when i try move this modela windows i create, no move weel not fluid when move, i don´t know why, if problem it´s jquery UI or howewer exists other plugin better for draggable elements

Comment: no i wanted final generated code, anyway can you make a codepen that works like your code ? it's very hard to help not seeing the problem

Comment: I do not see where you are using jQuery UI in any of your Fiddles.

Comment: @CarlosJavierFernándezSouto Please provide a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve